# build ionic 4 cordova 9 platform android@8

Tags: gradle, ionic4

i have fist project the new system and run start ionic project and build project

my project 
info
ionic 4
cordova 9
node js 12
platform android@8
when 
i how build my project

error message

```
 Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip
 ................................
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip
................................
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

Comment: Which is cmd using for the build?

Comment: yes open cmd type ionic cordova build android --minifycss --optimizejs --minifyjs --proid --release